# android 4 onCreateDialog return type incompatible when overriding

Tags: java, android

The code below won't compile. I understand that when doing an override, the 
replacement class must match the signature of the original class exactly,
but I think I'm following the example from the Android documentation carefully.

**error messages:**

```
overrides android.app.Activity.onCreateDialog
The return type is incompatible with Activity.onCreateDialog(int)
```

**`onCreateDialog()` method:**

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case 0:
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setTitle("This is a dialog with a stupid message...")

            //more code here setting additional properties
            );
    return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a default return block in your switch or a return after the switch.  You can return null in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

The `onCreateDialog()` method requires a Bundle as the argument, not an int. You should pass in a Bundle that contains the int id and retrieve that value from the Bundle for use in the switch statement.

Comment: I think one can but that was depreciated long ago. See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateDialog%28int%29

Comment: @ShobhitPuri ahh thanks. I didn't know that. So then this may depend upon API

Comment: To be clear, the one that takes an integer id *without* an additional `Bundle` argument is deprecated.

Comment: I may have been thinking of the onCreateDialog method used when using DialogFragments.